# Amazon Connet's getCurrentMetricData is not a function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

Recently I am working on a project with Amazon Lambda.

I created a lambda function as following

```
var AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    var connect = new AWS.Connect({apiVersion: '2017-08-08'});
    var params = {
        InstanceId: '' /* required */
    };
    connect.getCurrentMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else   {
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            callback(null, data);
      }           // successful response
    });

    // const response = {
    //         statusCode: 200,
    //         body: JSON.stringify(typeof connect.getCurrentMetricData)
    // };
    // callback(null, response);
};
```

But the log said connect.getCurrentMetricData is not a function.

Anyone can help me with this error ? Thanks a lot.

ps, I wrote the code in Amazon Lambda online editor (nodejs 8.10) and I tested other connect's functions like createUser, deleteUser, the typeof result is function. Only when it comes to getCurrentMetricData, the typeof result will be undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var AWS = require ('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'your Region';
var connect = new AWS.Connect(); 

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var AGENTS_ON_CALL_VALUE;
var dataContent = {
  CurrentMetrics: [  
    { Name: 'AGENTS_ON_CALL',
      Unit: 'COUNT'
    },
  ],
  Filters: { 
    Channels: [ 'VOICE' ],
    Queues: [ 'Your Queue ID']
  },
  InstanceId: 'Connect InstanceID',
  Groupings: [ 'QUEUE' ],
  MaxResults: 1
};

connect.getCurrentMetricData(dataContent, function(err, data) {
    var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(data);
    if (err){
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else{    
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
        AGENTS_ON_CALL_VALUE = obj.MetricResults[0].Collections[0].Value;
        console.log(AGENTS_ON_CALL_VALUE);    
        callback(null,"Finish getting Data"); 
    }  
});
}
```

Problem Solved. Get the Newest AWS-SDK. Otherwise, it will return getCurrentMetricData is not a function error.

Comment: How do you get newest sdk on the lamdba function? Do you add it via zip? is it the only solution?

Comment: What does your test event look like?

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue with AWS connect.listQueues is not a function.
Update the npm module "aws-sdk" and it should run fine.

```
npm i aws-sdk --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the SDK, you’re using the built in package in Lambda it might not have compatible with this method included, yet. Also, You will need to create a deployment package that includes a version that supports the method.

**Latest supported Lambda version:** `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html`

**Deployment Packages:** `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html`

Finally, the Queue Id needs to be ARN or queue ID not the name.